# How to hide button according to user login in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have some sort of problem to hide the button after any user login.  The below snap/image explains my problem:

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQWRm.png)
[image]

In the above image, you see both user i.e "wajid" and "aamir" have visible of edit button.

Now I want this if "wajid" are login than edit button just show for wajid not for "Aamir".

During Login my session is:

```
Session["UserName"]
```

I tried to do this, but it does not work:

```
string SessionName=Session["UserName"].ToString();
if (SessionName == FirstName)
{
   for (int i = 0; i <DealPointsCommentlist1.Items.Count; i++)
   {
        Edit =(LinkButton)DealPointsCommentlist1.Items[i].FindControl("EditCommentLnkbtn");                        
        Edit.Visible =true;
   }
}
else
{
   for (int i = 0; i < DealPointsCommentlist1.Items.Count; i++)
   {
         Edit =(LinkButton)DealPointsCommentlist1.Items[i].FindControl("EditCommentLnkbtn");
   }                   
        Edit.Visible = false;
 }
```

Kindly reply me and provide some sort of example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code.

```
  string SessionName=Session["UserName"].ToString();
if (SessionName == FirstName)
{
   for (int i = 0; i <DealPointsCommentlist1.Items.Count; i++)
   {
        LabelName = (Label)DealPointsCommentlist1.Items[i].FindControl("lblFirstName");
        if(LabelName.Text == SessionName)
        {
           Edit = (LinkButton)DealPointsCommentlist1.Items[i].FindControl("EditCommentLnkbtn");                        
        Edit.Visible =true;
        }
        else 
       {
          Edit =(LinkButton)DealPointsCommentlist1.Items[i].FindControl("EditCommentLnkbtn");                        
          Edit.Visible =false;
       }
   }
}
else
{
   for (int i = 0; i < DealPointsCommentlist1.Items.Count; i++)
   {
         Edit =(LinkButton)DealPointsCommentlist1.Items[i].FindControl("EditCommentLnkbtn");
   }                   
        Edit.Visible = false;
 }
```

Hope It helps.

Comment: I get first name at login time

Comment: Its work condition when condition true it not show just for that name its problem